# ñ character displaying incorrectly

Tags: php, html

I have a problem with a single character in the name of a picture I am trying to put up on my website. The file name is `jalapeño.jpg`  and it works perfectly locally. However, when I put my files on the server and view it from public it hands me the error,

> jalape%C3%B1opepper.jpg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Also, keep in mind that this name was outputted by javascript in a jQuery AJAX request.

I've searched around but none of the suggested solutions work. Like:

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
mb_http_output('UTF-8');
mb_http_input('UTF-8');
mb_language('uni');
mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8');
ob_start('mb_output_handler');
```

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary that it has a ñ? Just use n instead. As a fellow spanish speaking programmer for 5 years in multiple companies I have never seen anyone use ñ in a file name.

Comment: Please edit your question and show your HTML / JQuery code

Comment: are you using apache?

Comment: Is the file name `jalapeño.jpg` or `jalapeñopepper.jpg`?

Comment: It's actually necessary for it to have a ñ character. But i appreciate your concern @prgrm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes from javascript/ajax as you say then you can decode it with [decodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent)

```js
console.log(decodeURIComponent('jalape%C3%B1opepper.jpg'));
```